# PHP PDO - Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I searched for people having the same problem but didn't find the answer which helped me specificly out yet, so I hope you can help me with this one.

I have the following code:

**inc_db.php**

```
class Database {
private $user = "myusername"; // just changed from my original one of course
private $pass = "mypassword"; // just changed from my original one of course
private $db = "mydb";
private $host = "localhost";
private $dbh;
private $error;
private $stmt;

public function __construct(){
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );

    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db12440376-voba, db12440376-voba, vobaschoe()#135");
        return $this->dbh;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($query){
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if (is_null($type)) {
      switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
          break;
        case is_bool($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
          break;
        case is_null($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
          break;
        default:
          $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute(){
    $this->stmt->execute();   
}

public function resultset(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function close_con(){
    $this->dbh = null;
}
}
```

**ajax_login.php**

```
session_start();
ob_start();
include_once("../php/inc_db.php");
$dbh = new Database();

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$dbh->query("SELECT user, pass, rest FROM voba_user WHERE user = :user AND    pass = :pass");
$dbh->bind(":user", $username);
$dbh->bind(":pass", $password);

if($dbh->execute()){
    while($row = $dbh->stmt->fetchObject()){
        if($row->user == $username &&
            $row->pass == $password){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row->user;
            $_SESSION['rest'] = $row->rest;
            echo $_SESSION["user"];
            echo $_SESSION["rest"];
        }
    }   
}
```

and the jquery ajax request is this

**absagen.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
        username = $("input[name=username]").val();
        password = $("input[name=password]").val();
        $.ajax({
          url: "../ajax/ajax_login.php",
          data: { user: username, pass: password },
          type: "post",
          async: true,
          success: function(data){
            if(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.indexOf("User") > -1){
                    rest = "User";
                } else {
                    rest = "Admin";
                }
            }
          }
        });
        p = $(document.createElement("p"));
        if(rest == "Admin") {
            text = $(document.createTextNode("Hallo " + username + ". Admin"));
        } else {
            text = $(document.createTextNode("Hallo " + username));
        }
        p.append(text);
        $("#content").append(p);
    });
```

The error I get is:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in **/is/htdocs/wp12440376_DDP0E7D8ZQ/www/php/inc_db.php** on line **26**

I know its something with the scope but I really can't figure out what's wrong.
Can someone tell me and explain to me what I did wrong?
I build the connection to the database in the class itself so why is there a problem with it?

Comment: I'm skeptical of this line `$this->dbh = new PDO( ...)`. (did you accidentally leave your DB user/password in there?). more arguments are required for some DBs - I think MySQL is one of them.

Comment: As answered, you might have a caught exception there from PDO.

Also, you might want to remove that return statement. AFAIK, constructors don't return anything anyway and you might just confuse yourself there since you are expecting a Database class and not a PDO class

Answer (score 3):

Your error is saying that you did not connect to your server. You try/catch for an error, but you never die on it nor do you show that an error has occurred. When you try to prepare your query, there is no db object because the object failed to be created. Check your settings to connect.

Also, why do you have a return statement in your constructor? You shouldn't be returning anything. The constructor creates the object from that class and $dbh is assigned the object.